# Loading data into HBASE using importtsv causes error

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to load a data from CSV File into HBASE using importtsv tool. I have set up a cluster of 3 machines. 
This is my hbase-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://ec2-54-190-103-64.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
 <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
   <value>ec2-54-203-95-235.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com</value>
  </property>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2222</value>
   </property>
   <property>
   <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
   <value>/home/ubuntu/zookeeper</value>
   <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
   The directory where the snapshot is stored.
    </description>
 </property>
 </configuration>
```

When i start and run jps. Under Master Node i see HMaster and under datanodes i see Hquorumpeer and Hregionserver
When i try to load data i get following error

```
INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server       localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
 14/08/11 07:41:28 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null,    unexpected     error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
   14/08/11 07:41:28 WARN zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Possibly transient   ZooKeeper    exception: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException:    KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
 14/08/11 07:41:28 INFO util.RetryCounter: Sleeping 8000ms before retry #3...
  14/08/11 07:41:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server   localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

Not sure what is the issue with zookeeper. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following property in your hbase-site.xml file(both master and slaves)

```
<property>
 <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
 <value>1000</value>
</property>
```